# Images not Appearing in Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

The following code looks daunting, but a lot of it is repetitive. Try clicking on the red buttons.

```html
<body>
<ul id="carousel" class="carousel">
<button id="moveSlideLeft" class="moveSlide moveSlideLeft"></button>
<div id="track" class="track">
<li class="slide1" data-shown="true2" title="true2"><img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Frajatbhageria%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F09%2Fcode-copy-1200x1200.jpg"></li>
<li class="slide2" data-shown="false3" title="false3"><img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Frajatbhageria%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F09%2Fcode-copy-1200x1200.jpg"></li>
<li class="slide3" data-shown="false1" title="false1"><img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Frajatbhageria%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F09%2Fcode-copy-1200x1200.jpg"></li>
</div>
<button id="moveSlideRight" class="moveSlide moveSlideRight"></button>
</ul>
</body>
<style>
.carousel {
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
}
.moveSlideLeft {
 left: 0px;
}
.moveSlideLeft>img {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.moveSlide {
 margin: none;
 padding: none;
 width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
 border: none;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}
.carousel>.track {
 margin: none;
 padding: none;
 left: 0px;
 width: 99px;
 height: 100px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}
.carousel>.track>li[data-shown="false1"] {
 transform: translateX(-99px);
 z-index: 0;
 transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}
.carousel>.track>li[data-shown="true2"] {
 transform: translateX(0px);
 z-index: 2;
 transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}
.carousel>.track>li[data-shown="false3"] {
 transform: translateX(99px);
 z-index: 0;
 transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}
.carousel>.track>li>img {
 float: left;
  width: 99px;
  height: 100px;
}
.moveSlideRight {
 left: 80px;
}
.moveSlideRight>img {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}
</style>
<script>
const left = document.getElementById("moveSlideLeft");
const right = document.getElementById("moveSlideRight");
left.onclick = function() {
 var carouselValues = [];
 var tagReferences = document.getElementById("carousel").getElementsByTagName("li");
 for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
  carouselValues[i] = tagReferences[i].dataset.shown;
 }
 var placeholder;
 for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
  if (carouselValues[i] == "true2") {
   placeholder = i;
   break; 
  }
 }
 if (placeholder == 0) {
  carouselValues[0] = "false3";
  carouselValues[1] = "false1";
  carouselValues[2] = "true2";
 }
 else if (placeholder == 1) {
  carouselValues[0] = "true2";
  carouselValues[1] = "false3";
  carouselValues[2] = "false1";
 }
 else if (placeholder == 2) {
  carouselValues[0] = "false1";
  carouselValues[1] = "true2";
  carouselValues[2] = "false3";
 }
 for (var i = 0; i<=2; i++) {
  tagReferences[i].dataset.shown = carouselValues[i];
  tagReferences[i].title = carouselValues[i];
 }
}
right.onclick = function() {
 var carouselValues = [];
 var tagReferences = document.getElementById("carousel").getElementsByTagName("li");
 for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
  carouselValues[i] = tagReferences[i].dataset.shown;
 }
 var placeholder;
 for (var i = 0; i<=2; i++) {
  if (carouselValues[i] == "true2") {
   placeholder = i;
   break; 
  }
 }
 if (placeholder == 0) {
  carouselValues[0] = "false1";
  carouselValues[1] = "true2";
  carouselValues[2] = "false3";
 }
  else if (placeholder == 1) {
  carouselValues[0] = "false3";
  carouselValues[1] = "false1";
  carouselValues[2] = "true2";
 }
  else if (placeholder == 2) {
  carouselValues[0] = "true2";
  carouselValues[1] = "false3";
  carouselValues[2] = "false1";
 }
 for (var i = 0; i<=2; i++) {
  tagReferences[i].dataset.shown = carouselValues[i];
  tagReferences[i].title = carouselValues[i];
 }  
}
</script>
```

I don't know why only one image is showing up. I'm trying to make a sliding carousel. Every time a button is clicked, the data-shown attribute is changed. Based on the value of the data-shown attribute, a new slide should slide in. Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `position: absolute` to `carousel>.track>li>img` to list them in one line because you position them floating to left but in top of each other

```js
const left = document.getElementById("moveSlideLeft");
    const right = document.getElementById("moveSlideRight");
    left.onclick = function() {
     var carouselValues = [];
     var tagReferences = document.getElementById("carousel").getElementsByTagName("li");
     for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
      carouselValues[i] = tagReferences[i].dataset.shown;
     }
     var placeholder;
     for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
      if (carouselValues[i] == "true2") {
       placeholder = i;
       break; 
      }
     }
     if (placeholder == 0) {
      carouselValues[0] = "false3";
      carouselValues[1] = "false1";
      carouselValues[2] = "true2";
     }
     else if (placeholder == 1) {
      carouselValues[0] = "true2";
      carouselValues[1] = "false3";
      carouselValues[2] = "false1";
     }
     else if (placeholder == 2) {
      carouselValues[0] = "false1";
      carouselValues[1] = "true2";
      carouselValues[2] = "false3";
     }
     for (var i = 0; i<=2; i++) {
      tagReferences[i].dataset.shown = carouselValues[i];
      tagReferences[i].title = carouselValues[i];
     }
    }
    right.onclick = function() {
     var carouselValues = [];
     var tagReferences = document.getElementById("carousel").getElementsByTagName("li");
     for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
      carouselValues[i] = tagReferences[i].dataset.shown;
     }
     var placeholder;
     for (var i = 0; i<=2; i++) {
      if (carouselValues[i] == "true2") {
       placeholder = i;
       break; 
      }
     }
     if (placeholder == 0) {
      carouselValues[0] = "false1";
      carouselValues[1] = "true2";
      carouselValues[2] = "false3";
     }
      else if (placeholder == 1) {
      carouselValues[0] = "false3";
      carouselValues[1] = "false1";
      carouselValues[2] = "true2";
     }
      else if (placeholder == 2) {
      carouselValues[0] = "true2";
      carouselValues[1] = "false3";
      carouselValues[2] = "false1";
     }
     for (var i = 0; i<=2; i++) {
      tagReferences[i].dataset.shown = carouselValues[i];
      tagReferences[i].title = carouselValues[i];
     }  
    }
```

```css
.carousel {
     list-style-type: none;
     position: relative;
    }
    .moveSlideLeft {
     left: 0px;
    }
    .moveSlideLeft>img {
     width: 10px;
     height: 10px;
     transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    .moveSlide {
     margin: none;
     padding: none;
     width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: red;
     border: none;
     float: left;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
    }
    .carousel>.track {
     margin: none;
     padding: none;
     left: 0px;
     width: 99px;
     height: 100px;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: absolute;
    }
    .carousel>.track>li[data-shown="false1"] {
     transform: translateX(-99px);
     z-index: 0;
     transition: transform 1s ease-out;
    }
    .carousel>.track>li[data-shown="true2"] {
     transform: translateX(0px);
     z-index: 2;
     transition: transform 1s ease-out;
    }
    .carousel>.track>li[data-shown="false3"] {
     transform: translateX(99px);
     z-index: 0;
     transition: transform 1s ease-out;
    }
    .carousel>.track>li>img {
     float: left;
      width: 99px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .moveSlideRight {
     left: 80px;
    }
    .moveSlideRight>img {
     width: 10px;
     height: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <ul id="carousel" class="carousel">
    <button id="moveSlideLeft" class="moveSlide moveSlideLeft"></button>
    <div id="track" class="track">
    <li class="slide1" data-shown="true2" title="true2"><img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Frajatbhageria%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F09%2Fcode-copy-1200x1200.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide2" data-shown="false3" title="false3"><img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Frajatbhageria%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F09%2Fcode-copy-1200x1200.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide3" data-shown="false1" title="false1"><img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Frajatbhageria%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F09%2Fcode-copy-1200x1200.jpg"></li>
    </div>
    <button id="moveSlideRight" class="moveSlide moveSlideRight"></button>
    </ul>
```